# Unable to retrieve a array list item from user input

Tags: java, arraylist

So im trying to retrieve a value that I stored in my arraylist based on which state abbreviation the user inputs. The arraylist contains the state abbreviation, state name, and population. All of these items are read into the arraylist by a csv file using a loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Prog1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inFile = null;
        ArrayList<State> list = new ArrayList<State>();

        try {
            inFile = new Scanner(new File( "states.txt" ) );
        }
        catch( FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Error: File states.txt not found");
        }

        State s;
        String abb;
        String name;
        double population;

        while(inFile.hasNext()) {
            String file = inFile.nextLine();        
            String[] tokens = file.split( ",[ ]*" );
            abb = tokens[0];
            name = tokens[1];
            population = Double.parseDouble( tokens[2] );
            s = new State(abb, name, population);
            list.add(s);

        }
        System.out.printf( "%-13s %-13s %3s\n", "Abbreviation", "Name", "Population" );
        System.out.printf( "%-13s %-14s %3s\n", "----", "------", "---------", "\n" );
        for( int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ )
        {
            s = list.get(i);
            System.out.printf( "%-13s %-15s %,2.0f\n", 
                    s.getAbb(), s.getName(), s.getPopulation() );
        }
        System.out.println("Enter State Abbreviation:");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userState = scan.next();
        State search = new State(userState);
        int index = list.indexOf( search );
        if( index >= 0) {
            State located = list.get(index);
            System.out.printf( userState, located.getName(), located.getPopulation());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(userState + " not found");
        }



    }

}



public class State {
    private String abb;
    private String name;
    private double population;

    public State(String abb) {
        super();
        this.abb = abb;
    }

    public State(String abb, String name, double population) {
        super();
        this.abb = abb;
        this.name = name;
        this.population = population;
    }

    public String getAbb() {
        return abb;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object arg)
    {
        return this.abb.equals( ((State)arg).name );
    }   


}
```

Comment: `State` does not have a superclass. Why is `super()` being called in the constructor?

Comment: @AnilM Every class is implicitly a subclass of Object when it does not extends to other class.

Answer (score 0):

According the condition you want to filter the items is by `abbr`, so I would believe you should change:

```
 return this.abb.equals(((State)arg).name);
```

by

```
return this.abb.equals(((State)arg).abbr);
```